# Profile picture in column Person of a list shows in Microsoft Lists but not in Microsoft Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have set my profile picture in Delve. And my profile picture shows in all Office 365 apps.
I have created a Sharepoint list and set the profile picture of the column "Person" with json-code.
The strange thing is my profile picture is shown in Microsoft Lists but not Microsoft Teams. And i know for certain that the problem isn't in the JSON-code.

Does anyone know why?

Greetings,

Peter kiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, the Teams login user profile picture or list column profile picture will be displayed as follows:

[image]

Pleae sign out and sign in again to compare the result.

My test column-formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + @currentField.email",
            "title": "@currentField.title"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have logged off and on several times. But no luck. With the code is nothing wrong. Gr. Peter

Comment: Whether other users occur the same issue? It seems that the issue is caused by Microsoft Teams, not SharePoint list.